# Javascript/CSS arrows that move with page anchors?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I tried inspecting the elements for this website, but I could not figure out how they got the CSS triangle to move to different nav elements when a different page anchor is clicked.

See website: [www.simple.com](http://www.simple.com)

Comment: Have a look at Remy Sharp's [Scroll Linked Navigation](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/scroll-linked-navigation/); it's almost exactly the same thing, with the additional element of animating the triangle image's position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrow is a CSS sprite contained in `http://simple.com/img/sprites.png`. It's set up in the CSS with transitions as follows:

```
#main-nav #nav-arrow {
    -webkit-transition: left opacity;
    -moz-transition: left opacity;
    -o-transition: left opacity;
    transition: left opacity;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    width: 22px;
    height: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    text-indent: -10000px;
    background: url("/img/sprites.png") no-repeat -577px -52px
}
```

That does the animation when the `left` property of the CSS changes. The `left` property is altered by Javascript hooked from the main navigation library that drives the site, [NavSimple](http://mootools.net/forge/p/navsimple), in the (customised and minified) `https://www.simple.com/js/brawndo.min2175719530.js`. The more general NavSimple code to do the navigation also triggers custom Javascript that moves the arrow's left position to halfway along the active navigation element (it's subtracting eleven pixels because the arrow is 22 pixels wide):

```
this.nav_arrow.setStyle("left",d.getPosition(this.nav_wrapper).x+(d.getWidth()/2-11))}
```

And that's basically how it works. Nice site, very well-engineered, I'd say. (The navigation arrow is actually a `div` containing a letter "V", so it'll still look like an arrow even if the background images don't load, which I thought was a nice touch.)

Having said all that, I think this question might be a bit too specific to survive...

Comment: Exactly the information I needed. Thanks for the detailed response.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like the triangle moves until the page has scrolled to the specified content. You could use the `window.scrollY` value to evaluate to which button the triangle should move to.

I'd guess the animation for the triangle is done by a function which gets called at both the `window.onscroll` event. And by a callback to the scrolling animation function triggered by the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah there is some very cool stuff going on on that site. Its all CSS transitions, I would expect the use of Adobe Edge or LESS with something like that.

The brawdndo.js seems to be apart of moo-growing-input

demo here http://www.ohloh.net/p/moo-growing-input

source here https://github.com/3n/moo-growing-input

Answer (score -2):

I'd bet it's JavaScript just animating the triangle, you couldn't possibly do this in pure CSS.